# Proactive Messages in Waterfall Dialogs Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I need to include the concept of the proactive message into the waterfall dialog, are there samples to guide through implementation?

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2995

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is Trevor's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft samples on GitHub are a good place to start, here's a proactive message sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages

Here's a Waterfall dialog sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/43.complex-dialog